# Вытянуть ссылки из IMG

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть такая конструкция

```
<p>
    <img src="img.png">
</p>
```

Нужно вытянуть из img ссылку на картинку средствами PHP. Сайт на WordPress работает.

Comment: Не надо плодить вопросы. Надо было отредактировать предыдущий вопрос, добавив в него эту информацию.

Comment: Ответил вам в предыдущем вопросе.